# Безопасное хранение пароля

Tags: c#, .net

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите,как организовать безопасное хранение пароля от SMTP,чтобы ни в app.config?,ни при прогоне рефлетктором а-ля ILSpy,NET Reflector пароль не отображался?

Делал SecureString,но он отлично отображается через проги названные выше. После прогона конфига через aspnet_regiis теряется возможность использования на другой машине без манипуляций

Comment: Чтобы данные можно было расшифровать на другом компьютере, ключ шифрования должен быть у пользователя, чтобы он ввёл его на том компьютере. То есть пользователю вместо одного пароля (от SMTP) надо будет помнить другой (от защищённого хранилища). И в чём тогда смысл вообще хранить пароль в конфигурационном файле?

Comment: @Arhad поэтому этот вариант и не подошёл. Сама программа по себе простая. Обычный монитор с отправкой логов по событию,т.е интерфейса и взаимодействия с пользователем нет,поэтому вариант с вводом пароля вообще никак не подходит

Comment: А что если хранить пароль в хранилище паролей пользователя, которое реализовано операционной системой?

Comment: @eri А разве там не все могут смотреть пароли? Просто не хочется нигде показывать пароль от ящика

Comment: _"После прогона конфига через aspnet_regiis теряется возможность использования на другой машине без манипуляций"_ один раз импортировать rsa-контейнер на другую машину - это что, сложная манипуляция?

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT `не хочется нигде показывать пароль от ящика` Действуйте по правилу "все что находится на машине пользователя может быть вскрыто". Если уж не хотите светить нигде свой ящик - сделайте отдельный веб-сервис, через который и отправляйте нужные вам данные.

Comment: @Геннадий П только клиент-сервер? Думал мало ли есть какая реализация,которая позволяет хранить только хэш пароля